# Authentication code Java

Tags: java, authentication, hashset

after some research and help from a friend I could make a method (authentificate) that compare the username and password given by the user in the Main and the ones presents in the loginList. The problems is the methode always return false, and I can't find the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String username;
    String password;
    System.out.println("Enter your username");
    username = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your password");
    password = input.nextLine();
    UserList test2 = new UserList();
    if (test2.authenticate(username, password) == true) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Username or/and password are wrong.");
    }
}

}
```

User

```
public class User {

protected String username;
protected String password;

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof User) {
        return ((User) o).username.equals(username);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.username);
    return hash;
}
}
```

UserList

```
public class UserList {

private HashSet<User> loginList;emphasized text

public UserList() {
    Scanner scan;
    loginList = new HashSet();
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File("src/boitedejeux/Logins.txt"));
        String ligne = scan.nextLine();
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            ligne = scan.nextLine();
            String[] res = ligne.split(",");
            loginList.add(new User(res[0], (res[1])));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Erreur");
    }
}

public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    if (null == loginList) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The user list isn't initialised");
    }

    return loginList.stream()
            .filter(usern -> usern.getUsername().equals(username))
            .filter(passw -> passw.getPassword().equals(password))
            .findFirst()
            .isPresent();
}
}
```

Login.txt

```
Test, Password
Test2, Password2
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces after commas in your txt, or change the line of `String[] res = ligne.split(",")` to split with spaces `String[] res = ligne.split(", ")`.